# How can I merge two Stack Exchange accounts and choose which account is kept?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I followed the instructions for merging accounts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts), but after verifying the merge via both emails, I only get one option of the merge order.

How can I merge my other account into *this* one, and not the other way around?

Comment: You can't. [The main account will always be the oldest (lowest ID number) one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256919/241919).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this seems like an arbitrary constraint. Any idea on how to submit a feature request for that?

Comment: You can either post it on here or Meta Stack Exchange and see if SE staff may consider it. Also, consider [the guide to write a good feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258136/241919), especially by providing supportive reasons. This is because while the community can evaluate and give feedback/criticism to the request, only SE staff has the final word, and they have limited resources.

Comment: @JohannesPertl This decision was made because allowing merges in the other direction causes weird side effects. Users could choose the direction in the past and we changed the code to start enforcing one direction because of the headaches it occasionally caused. It's not something we'd reconsider.

Comment: @JohannesPertl What difference would it make? You can always change the name of the account after the merge to whatever you prefer.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The user ID changes which matters somewhat in a few scenarios. For example, tracking which user shared links to a specific post is tied to user ID, not the name. There are probably other examples as well I'm failing to think of.

Comment: @animuson I assume the weird side effects in question are related to, for example, the resulting account having posts created before the account itself?

Comment: @RyanM yes, that is something that's nice to prevent. It was more backend account-related issues that could sprout up in these situations. Things that required devs to keep fixing. Cosmetic issues are one thing, but spending time to manually fix accounts is another. The CreationDate issue can still occur via our migration system too.